# Puzzling memory leak when adding image to a contact on IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts, abaddressbook

I currently have a leak on this line in instruments, I leak a few hundred K each time this is called-

```
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]);
ABPersonSetImageData(newRecord, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
```

When I rem out the above lines, I'm good.

dataRef is only mentioned here in the entire program. I tried CFrelease-ing it as a test, but that causes a crash due to referencing a deallocated object.

i tried concatenating it all into one line,

```
ABPersonSetImageData(newRecord,(CFDataRef) UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]), nil);
```

but I got the same results.

I would half-expect a leak the first time, as Imagenamed is well known to cache the image object, and the call was reported to leak pre-iOS4, but I wouldn't expect ongoing leaks.

Any ideas? related questions have been raised here before a few times but no-one seemed to have an answer.

Comment: Do these leaks appear on the device? Results from the Simulator will often show bogus leaks.

Comment: Are you sure you're CFRelease'ing newRecord, once you're done with it ?

Comment: Actually I don't appear to be releasing it (and I get an odd bug elsewhere if I do.) I see that it is retained throughout the life of this view controller, but not dealloced on exit. Its a while since I worked on this one, I'll investigate further when I get back to this project for the next update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need not to worry about that object. Since `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will return you an `autoreleased` object, so there won't be any memory leak. Since `dataRef` is an `autoreleased` object you should not release it manually.

Comment: I lose a couple of hundred K each time I use that line, though (measuring in instruments). I have slightly improved the situation by only creating the contact picture when I create the contact (I was doing it whenever I updated previously) but I would still like to solve this.